# HighCharts Drilldown issue in pie

Tags: highcharts

Can someone tell me why this chart is rendering properly in drill up? The code is wrapping arc3d. I have provided the code and also the JFiddle for reference. When you click on the graph it drills down perfectly but while drilling up the graph is not rendering properly. it holds the color of the drilled slice.

(http://jsfiddle.net/subhasispatra/np0bn3ps/)

```
$(function () {
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        drillUpText: '<Back'
    }
});
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype, 'arc3d', function (proceed) {
    var result = proceed.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
    result.fadeIn = result.show;
    return result;
});

$('#container').highcharts({
    "plotOptions": {
        "pie": {
            "point": {
                "events": {
                    "click": function () {
                        if (this.options != undefined && this.options != null && this.options.url != null && this.options.url.length > 0) location.href = this.options.url;
                        else return;
                    }
                }
            },
                "dataLabels": {
                "enabled": true,
                    "style": {
                    "fontWeight": "bold",
                        "fontFamily": "Arial",
                        "fontSize": "10"
                },
                    "color": "#000000"
            },
                "shadow": true,
                "curson": "pointer",
                "depth": 30,
                "allowPointSelection": true,
                "showInLegend": true
        }
    },
        "drilldown": {
        "series": [{
            "id": "Draft",
                "data": [{
                "name": "15-21 DAYS",
                "url": "http://www.google.com",
                "y": 1
            }, {
                "name": "22-30 DAYS",
                "url": "http://www.google.com",
                "y": 1
            }]
        }, {
            "id": "Canceled",
                "data": [{
                "name": "15-21 DAYS",
                "url": "http://www.google.com",
                "y": 0
            }, {
                "name": "22-30 DAYS",
                "url": "http://www.google.com",
                "y": 1
            }]
        }],
            "drillUpButton": {
            "relativeTo": "spacingBox",
                "theme": {
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "7pt"
                }
            },
                "y": 0,
                "x": 0
        }
    },
        "series": [{
        "name": "SERIES",
            "data": [{
            "drilldown": "Draft",
            "name": "Draft",
            "y": 2
        }, {
            "drilldown": "Canceled",
            "name": "Canceled",
            "y": 1
        }]
    }],
        "yAxis": {
        "title": {
            "style": {
                "color": "#000000",
                    "fontSize": "10"
            }
        },
            "labels": {
            "style": {
                "fontWeight": "normal",
                    "color": "#000000",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial",
                    "fontSize": "10"
            }
        }
    },
        "title": {
        "text": "Orders created in last 30 days"
    },
        "legend": {
        "itemStyle": {
            "fontWeight": "normal",
                "color": "#000000",
                "fontFamily": "Arial",
                "fontSize": "10"
        },
            "layout": "vertical",
            "align": "left",
            "verticalAlign": "middle"
    },
        "chart": {
        "renderTo": "container",
            "options3d": {
            "enabled": "true",
                "alpha": 40,
                "beta": 0,
                "depth": 40
        },
            "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)",
            "type": "pie"
    },
        "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },
        "xAxis": {
        "title": {
            "style": {
                "color": "#000000",
                    "fontSize": "10"
            }
        },
            "labels": {
            "style": {
                "fontWeight": "normal",
                    "color": "#000000",
                    "fontFamily": "Arial",
                    "fontSize": "10"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to 3D rendering. Disable 3D options and it'll work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I need 3d view of the graph. We can make 3d with drilldown. But I am not getting where is the issue?

Comment: I guess that is bug in the framework itself:
https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3534